# I'm using python-social-auth but my app isn't logging out when the user logs out of Google

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have python-social-auth working to authorize my app and everything works great. I can log into my app via OAuth2 and log out via typical Django logout.

**My problem: if a user logs out of Google (from GMail, for example), it does not log me out of my Django app.** I am still authorized as the Google user even though Google is logged out.

I have tried refreshing tokens via the load strategy below to "force" a check to make sure Google is still logged in and that isn't working.

```
social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')
access_token = social.get_access_token(load_strategy())
social.refresh_token(load_strategy())
```

I feel like I'm going down the wrong road. All I want to do is validate that Google is logged into still so I can consider my OAuth2 session valid. Is there a way to do this integrity check?

What am I doing wrong or do I need to do? My research so far suggests what I want is not even possible - I don't like that answer so hoping for a different one here.

Answer (score 0):

This looks impossible based on OAuth2's implementation.

I have given up trying to get this to be what I wanted it to be. I considered doing repeated OAuth2 requests periodically, but that seems laborious to the user since they would be prompted.

It seems the best approach is what Google itself uses:

**If a user is navigating to to a sensitive area of the app where they can perform functions that could be considered harmful or if they are navigating somewhere to get access to more sensitive information, consider re-authorizing with a fresh Oauth2 request.**

This isn't exactly what I want, but it looks like maybe what OAuth2 can offer.

I am also considering implementing a timer on OAuth2 and simply stating that if a login session is older than "X", force another OAuth2 challenge.

A blend of these strategies seems acceptable. I'm closing this for now - if anyone has a better suggestion or solution, please add it!